# SQL Hashbyte on set of values in multiple rows

Tags: sql, checksum

I have a table like below. I insert data in packages. I'd like to find out if package contains same values:

```
ID    Package   Value
1     A         001
2     A         002
3     A         004
---
12    C         001
13    C         002
14    C         009
---
20    F         001
21    F         002
---
25    G         001
26    G         002
27    G         004
```

I wonder how to put the values for each package into a Checksum (Hashbyte?) and compare. That should allow to find out that package A and package G have same content

I found that checksum_AGG is not good enough as values are varchars

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Remember that the SQL language *by design* does not specify *how* comparisons are performed by the engine. What you actually want is a normal set-operation. You don't need to dictate that a hash-set should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SQL Set Operators (`UNION`, `INTERSECT`, `EXCEPT`, etc) to see if two arbitrary sets of tuples are equivalent:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.PackagesAreEquivalent( @packageX nvarchar(10), @packageY nvarchar(10) )
    RETURNS bit
AS

DECLARE @ret bit = (
    CASE
        WHEN EXISTS(
            SELECT
                [Value]
            FROM
                MyTable
            WHERE
                Package = @packageX

            EXCEPT

            SELECT
                [Value]
            FROM
                MyTable
            WHERE
                Package = @packageY
        ) THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END
);

RETURN @ret;

END;
```

Usage:

```
SELECT dbo.PackagesAreEquivalent( 'A', 'G' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string aggregation.  In standard SQL, this uses `LISTAGG()` but the exact function name varies by database.  The idea is:

```
select value_list, listagg(package, ',') within group (order by package) as packages
from (select package,
             listagg(value, ',') within group (order by value) as value_list
      from t
      group by package
     ) p
group by value_list
having count(*) > 1;
```

Note that a "hash" function would not help, because that would only operate within one row.

The reference to `checksum_agg()` suggests that you are using SQL Server.  If so, the function for aggregating strings is `string_agg()`.

Comment: TIL I learned about `LISTAGG` (thanks!) - but after having now read about it from the spec I'm now withering in my pessimistic opinion that the ISO SQL committee is being awkward in their syntax inventions _just because they can_. I'm going to become _rich and famous_ after I finish devising my "What LESS/SASS is to CSS, my (thing) is to SQL". I've got a proof-of-concept working by hacking SSMS via .NET reflection and it ain't pretty. Lemme know if you're interested!